# problem with array modifier while trying to create a plant

Tags: modifiers

i am trying to create a plant, but when i am adding array modifier to a leaf and seting the properties that you can see on the screenshot below, it is having this strange distortion, so i want to know how to clean it up and where is my actual mistake

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object have a non-uniform size, specifically along the z axis and thus the slight displacement of the leaf is amplified along the z axis. So just apply the scale of the object using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> >> Scale.

The same problem may appear when the offset object have a non uniform size as well.

Comment: @travisscott Please accept the answer if it answers your question.